# Where to put node.js code in cPanel

Tags: node.js, backend

I am entirely new to backend development so this might be a ridiculously easy and straightforward question, but I'm really not sure. I am trying to learn node.js for backend development, and all of the tutorials I have seen so far show how node can be used to run JavaScript from the terminal and create a server on local host. While this is a neat thing to do, I am stuck there and having difficulty understanding where to put my node.js code on cPanel and how to use it effectively along with the rest of my html/css/js code; all the examples I have seen are very isolated and don't have much interaction with these other files.

Again, I don't have any backend experience, so it would not be very helpful to explain this concept relative to another server-side language like Python, Ruby, or PHP, as I really have no idea where I would put any of the code for any of that stuff either or how it fits into the bigger picture. If the answer could maybe touch on how to integrate Python or PHP as well and general patterns for backend development---the easy stuff everyone assumes but no one explains---it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What sort of hosting package do you have?

Comment: I'm using x10hosting's free plan.

Comment: You can't run Node on that. You either need a hosting package that supports it out of the box, or you need SSH access to the server's operating system to install it yourself. Their premium tier offers the latter, but even then I don't know if they'd support Node, as their support site makes no mention of it.  Sorry ):

Comment: What is the industry standard for hosting and using node?

Comment: Generally, you'll need some sort of VPS (virtual private server), which is basically where the hosting provider gives you a virtualized instance of Linux to do what you want with. Generally they cost money - I'm paying $5 a month on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) for one - but there's a couple of providers out there that do basic plans for free. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) is probably the best example of one of those (and provides a pretty neat command line interface for deploying your code), and I believe Microsoft Azure and Amazon Web Services have free plans too.

Comment: Openshift is free but somewhat complicated to setup.  Modulus is simple and easy to use, i highly recommend it for a beginner, but costs money.  Havent tried digitalocean.

Comment: @user949300 - Yeah, I think for a beginner going with one of the Platform-as-a-Service type hosts like Modulus, Azure or Heroku is better - DigitalOcean has been really good for me, but they basically just give you an Ubuntu box and leave you to do the rest.

Comment: Also, there is a list of [hosts that support Node on the Node.js Github wiki!](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Node-Hosting)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you put it.  However you probably want to keep it in the folder of the username which is using it.  I created a folder called app/ in my users folder and put all my crap in there.  Then you simply set it up to listen on a port approved by your host.

You can use a .htaccess file in your public_html folder to redirect to the correct port number.

Your node.js will handle routing.  So to go to certain css/html files you will have to set that up in your node.js code.